# Ruby on Rails 3 - Using Jquery dialog modal form with a has many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog, nested-forms

---

Hello People

I've working with jquery for a few days, and I've found an example of dialog modal form that works fine. [Here](https://github.com/ramblex/modal-form) is the example.

Since a couple of weeks ago I've been working with "nested-form" gem. I've tried the "Project has many tasks" and works fine.

So, what I want to do now is try to simulate the "nested form" using the jquery dialog modal form.

I mean

I have a table projects and a table tasks.
Project has many tasks (and obviously task belongs to project)

I create first a project, then I want to have a link or a button that displays the form to create tasks in a dialog form... but I need to get the id of the project to make the association with the task.

So I don't know how to "include" the project_id in the dialog form to create the associated tasks

Could anyone help me, please?